# Can we stop the perf test in gatling automatically when we reach a certain limit of 504s?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

Is it possible to stop the performance tests automatically when you reach a certain amount of 504s instead of running the tests fully? Is there any options available in Gatling to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible - gatling users are (by design) not aware of results from others. Likewise simulation level assertions are not checked until after all the users are complete.

The best you can do is to have .exitHereIfFailed in your scenario so that individual users don't keep performing their own actions after a 504 or other error

Depending on your scenarios, you might also be able to rework them to improve matters - eg: if you're not dependent on each user having a distinct authorisation etc, you could use fewer users in a simulation with looping inside scenarios. But this will be highly dependant on what you're modelling.